# Are python modules first class citizens?

Tags: python, module

I mean, can I create them dynamically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes:

```
>>> import types
>>> m = types.ModuleType("mymod")
>>> m
<module 'mymod' (built-in)>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create them dynamically, with the [imp.new_module](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.new_module) method.